# Poor performance when using the Calendar API in Java

Tags: java

The following code is giving very bad performance.
I've come to know that there are performance problems with the Calendar API

```
long startInMilliSec = measFileCreationTime_OssTime;
Calendar thisMoment = Calendar.getInstance();
long currentInMilliSec = thisMoment.getTime().getTime();

if (currentInMilliSec >= startInMilliSec) {
    return (true);
} else {
    return (false);
}
```

Is there any alternative for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use `System.currentTimeMillis()` to get the current time in millis since Dec, 1st 1970. Subtracting two millis values can be used to get the duration in millis between them. Calendar needs only to be used when interpreting the year, Month etc of such a milli value.

If you want to be even more precise, then you could use `System.nanoTime()` to get nano precision. The absolute nano value has no particular meaning in this case and can only be used for calculating time differences between subsequently taken nano values.

Comment: And shorter/simpler. Calendar/GregorianCalendar is one of the most chunky objects you might use. ;)